# Pack a JMeter Gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jmeter, pack

I'm trying to make a GUI for my JMeter plugin using [this API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/)

I want my `AbstractSamplerGui` to scroll when too many `JComponent` objects are created. If I create a panel with simple objects I have no issue.. the panel will scroll fine:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.VerticalPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.gui.AbstractSamplerGui;

...

public final class MyGui extends AbstractSamplerGui {
    public MyGui() {
        final VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            panel.add(new JLabel("TEST"));
            panel.add(new JTextArea());
        }
        add(panel);
    }
    ...
```

However, when I give the `JTextArea` objects a non-default size `new JTextArea(30, 30))`, the scroll bar doesn't notice that the page is any bigger.. meaning that half of the items extend out of the panel (unreachable).

I understand that you're supposed to call `pack` on a `JFrame` after you add items, but I don't know how I can do that here. `AbstractSamplerGui` extends `JPanel` which has no `pack` method.

I tried finding the `JFrame` using the JMeter API, but I've had no luck. I also don't think I can find the root frame using `SwingUtilities::getRoot` because this work is being done inside the constructor for the `JPanel`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `Why does anyone use swing?` - because it is easy to use and customize. Lack of knowledge about Swing is no reason to rant about it. The problem is with your custom code, not Swing. Who knows why your code doesn't work. "VerticalPanel" is a non-standard class and I have no idea what it does. The layout problem is probably in there.

Comment: @camickr its was more of a facetious comment :p Also VerticalPanel is part of the JMeter API. I'll add the imports

Comment: @camickr I just replaced `panel` with `JPanel panel = new JPanel(); panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));` and I see the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

> I just replaced panel with JPanel panel = new JPanel();

Yes, but we don't know what AbstractSamplerGui is doing. It may have some constraints on the width of components.

> I also don't think I can find the root frame using SwingUtilities::getRoot because this work is being done inside the constructor for the JPanel.

You can try adding an `AncestorListener` to your panel. The `ancestorAdded` event should be generated when the panel is added to a visible GUI. Then you should be able to get the parent window so you can pack it:

```
@Override
public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent e)
{
    JComponent component = e.getComponent();

    Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(component);

    window.pack();
}
```

Comment: Just tried this and unfortunately it did not fix the issue. I'm not sure what JMeter is doing under the hood to cause this behavior; maybe packing isn't the actual cause of my issue... I'll keep investigating. Thanks for the response :)